# Any information about losing Skill Points?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, technical-issues

I've spent my first five Points into different Perks in the Skill Trees. But at Level 6, I decided to save my Points for later (when my Smithing-Skill is grown up). Now, with Level 8, I wanted to hand them out ... But... They're (3 points) all gone!

Do you know, if they expire after some time or levels?

Can I get them back?

Answer (score 3):

They don't expire, I've done the same thing: hold onto skill points for several levels (currently, I have 5 unspent points).

If you haven't spent them, it sounds like you might've hit a bug. While there's a chance it might mark you a cheater (disputed), you can use the [following console command](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console) to get back your skill points:

```
player.addperk <perk ID>
```

Where `<perk ID>` is replaced with the code for the perk you wanted to spend your points on. [The UESP Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Template:Skills_in_Skyrim) contains a list of these codes.

But before doing that, I'd double check your perk trees and make sure you didn't accidentally spend them.

Comment: Thank you! While I'm playing on PS3 I cannot use your tip. I would suggest it's a bug then. I will try to figure it out (loading older savegames).

Comment: @fnst Ah, that stinks then :/ For what it's worth, I'm playing on the PS3 as well, so if it is a bug, it's not systemic. Hopefully you'll be fine when you load up an earlier save.

Comment: @MarkTrapp I may be wrong, but doesn't advskill advance your skill ranks, and isn't finst asking about perk points?

Comment: @Arkive Whoops, you're correct. Fixed.